# How to upload an image to FTP using FTPClient?

Tags: android, image, ftp

I'm using

```
FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
try
{
    con.connect(HOST);
    if (con.login (LOGIN, PASSWORD))
    {
        con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 
        InputStream instream = context.openFileInput(filename);
        con.storeFile(filename, instream);
        instream.close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try
{
    con.logout();
    con.disconnect();
}
```

With a textfile it works. With an image file, the image is very weird :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw790.jpg)

How to correct it?

Comment: Which ftp library are you using ? Try transferring the image in binary mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try changing the fileType :

```
con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
```

http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType%28int%29